# Allow leading and trailing space for NSTokenField

Tags: macos, cocoa, space, trailing, nstokenfield

I would like to allow leading and trailing space in NSTokenField, problem is that when it loses focus, the space is being trimmed automatically.
I've tried to customize delegated functions: editingStringForRepresentedObject and displayStringForRepresentedObject but still no luck...